# Multiplying a matrix with a scalar - dimensional consistency

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let us represent an $n\times 1$ vector as $\vert .\rangle$ and a $1\times n$ vector as $\langle . \vert$. Consider the following expression where $X$ and $Y$ are $n\times n$ matrices.

$$E(X) = \langle i \vert X\vert i\rangle Y$$

Suppose $Y$ can be written as a product of two more $n\times n$ matrices $A$ and $B$. Then

$$E(X) = \langle i \vert X\vert i\rangle AB = A\langle i \vert X\vert i\rangle B,$$

where the change of order is allowed since $\langle i \vert X\vert i\rangle$ is just a number. I'm not sure how to think about the terms $A\langle i \vert$ and $\vert i\rangle B$. They seem dimensionally inconsistent, yet they should work out to be an $n\times n$ matrix. What is the issue here?

Comment: Most of the time you can ignore the difference between scalar and matrix multiplication, but this time you cannot. Let us explicitly write $\cdot$ for scalar multiplication and reserve juxtaposition for matrix multiplication. Then your equation is $E(X) = (\langle i|X|i\rangle) \cdot (AB) = A \bigl((\langle i|X|i\rangle) \cdot B\bigr)$. Here you cannot extract $\langle i|$ and $|i\rangle$ out of the scalar multiplication to form $A\langle i|$ and $|i\rangle B$.

Comment: @Rahul ... unless you read the latter as a tensor product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A\langle i\vert$ is ***not*** an $N\times N$ matrix.  It is an $N\times N^2$ matrix.  More precisely, you should think of this (and correspondingly the other products in your question) as a *tensor product* of an $N\times N$ matrix with a $1\times N$ vector, that is,
$$ A\otimes \langle i\vert\ .$$

Answer (score -1):

Notice that $\langle i |\cdot X\cdot |i\rangle$ is not actually “just a number,” but really a $1\times 1$ matrix (because the product of two matrices is always a matrix). Since $\langle i|X|i\rangle$ is not a scalar, the product $\langle i|X|i\rangle Y$ is not well-defined, since $i$ is $1\times 1$ and $Y$ is $n\times n$.

Comment: Would you also say that a scalar product gives a $1\times 1$ matrix, not a number?  (Note that the $\vert i\rangle$ notation does denote vectors.)

Comment: @NorbertSchuch No, a product of two scalars gives a scalar, a product of a scalar and a matrix gives a matrix, and a product of two matrices *always* gives a matrix. Also, I am fairly certain that in the above question the OP was referring to the traditional matrix product, not the tensor product.

Comment: The post of the OP is related to [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/509070/kraus-operators-of-a-classical-quantum-channel), in which case this is an outer product (or tensor product, whatever you call it). -- Also, if you regard a vector as a $N\times 1$ matrix (which it is in a technical sense, e.g. when you do numerics), then the product above (for $X=Id$) is simply the scalar product, which gives a number.